# Backbone - Difference between Collection.add() / Collection.create()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am rather confused by the differences between the two. It seems like Collection.create() (fires `add` and `sync` events) can be seen as the combination of Collection.add() (fires `add`) and Model.save() (fires `sync`)?

Is the above assessment correct? What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's right. It's a shortcut method. [Documentation states](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create):

> **create** `collection.create(attributes, [options])`
>
> Convenience to create
>   a new instance of a model within a collection. Equivalent to
>   instantiating a model with a hash of attributes, saving the model to
>   the server, and adding the model to the set after being successfully
>   created.

And [annotated source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-105):

> Create a new instance of a model in this collection. Add the model to
>   the collection immediately, unless wait: true is passed, in which case
>   we wait for the server to agree.

This second description is a little bit more accurate as only passing `{wait:true}` has the effect of not adding a model to the collection in case of errors upon saving the model.

Comment: Is the model instance created added to the client side collection if and only if the server side addition successful?